# How to programmatically build NSArray of localized calendar month names?

Tags: iphone, ios, date, nsdate, nscalendar

I am in the process of localizing/internationalizing my iPhone app and have a question. In one place in my app, I show a list of the 12 months of the year. As it is in its currently non-localized state, I simply have the months January - December hard-coded into an NSArray. I'd like to use NSCalendar to programmatically build this NSArray of months based on the user's locale. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the localized name of the month from the NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
for ( int i = 0; i < 12; ++i ) {
    NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:i];
    [...]
}
[df release];
```

Comment: cool! pity it doesn't work in simulator, once i though it was a wrong method... till i tried it on device...  tks Volker

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it doesnt work in simulator, I was going nuts!

Answer (score 3):

Swift version....tried in playground

Provide the locale or use currentlocale

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

var formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "sv_SE") 
//formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // use this to find it automatically

print(formatter.monthSymbols)
```

RESULT

```
"["januari", "februari", "mars", "april", "maj", "juni", "juli", "augusti", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"]\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to do the iteration, just get the months directly:

```
NSDateFormatter dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Months = %@", dateFormatter.monthSymbols);
```

**Swift:**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
print("Months = \(dateFormatter.monthSymbols)")
```